# How to convert an array reference to an array in Perl?

Tags: perl

I know I can create an array and a reference to an array as follows:

```
my @arr = ();
my $rarr = \@arr;
```

I can then iterate over the array reference as follows:

```
foreach my $i (@{$rarr}){

}
```

Is there a way to copy or convert the array ref to a normal array so I can return it from a function? (Ideally without using that foreach loop and a push).

Comment: You cannot return an array in Perl. (you can however, return the list that an array contains)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have the answer in your question :-)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub foo() {
    my @arr = ();
    push @arr, "hello", ", ", "world", "\n";
    my $arf = \@arr;
    return @{$arf}; # <- here
}

my @bar = foo();
map { print; } (@bar);
```

Comment: can just `return @arr;`?

Answer (score 11):

Like this:

```
return @{$reference};
```

You're then just returning a dereferenced reference.

Comment: it returns an empty array this way

Answer (score 4):

you can copy the array simply by assigning to a new array:

```
my @copy_of_array = @$array_ref;
```

BUT, you don't need to do that just to return the modified array.  Since it's a reference to the array, updating the array through the reference is all you need to do!